# Our 8 year old son saw us having sex

Tags: primary-schooler, parents, age-appropriate, sex

Our 8 year old son saw my wife and I having sex the other day. Now I don't see anything wrong with it, yet my wife is unsure. What should happen here?

Comment: What are your wife's concerns? How much does your son know about sex already? How did he react?

Comment: I've deleted the photo. If there was a reason for having it then please restore it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site!  We've had a few questions on this topic, I've marked this as a duplicate of one of them; please let us know if there's something that is sufficiently different in your question that you need to have a separate set of answers.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is really a duplicate, as the other question was about a child 12 years old. That's 4 years older than in this case. That makes a difference. At 8 years old, a child may only have a very vague idea of what sex is. A 12 year old certainly will know what sex is, and may be getting interested in it himself.

Answer (score 3):

You should not make a huge deal of it, but take this opportunity to ask him if he has any questions, reassure him if he is upset, and provide him with age-appropriate education about human sexuality in a low-pressure setting. (There are lots of questions with more information about how to accomplish this available.)

Eight isn't too young for the non-graphic version, and either way I think it's best to have 'the talk' as a gradually evolving conversation over the course of growing up, rather than a confusing and uncomfortable info-dump to a teenager who has already gotten a good deal of (mis-)information from media and peers.

Kids have accidentally seen their parents making their new siblings since the dawn of time (and I imagine with far greater frequency in times and cultures where everyone lived in closer quarters).  Unless it's handled with an excess of shame, blame, or general drama, I don't think it's likely to be a major source of problems.